# Notification is not cancelled after calling notification.cancel

Tags: android

I create notification with action button. When clicking on action button, broadcast receiver is called. I am passing the notification ID in the intent

In the broadcast receiver I do the following

```
int notifId = intent.getIntExtra(Constants.NOTIF_ID, 0);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = 
        (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);   

mNotificationManager.cancel(notifId);
```

This is how I generate the notification

```java
int notifId = Util.random.nextInt(9000);
Intent mIntent = new Intent(con, NotificationBroadcastReceiver.class);
mIntent.putExtra(Constants.NOTIF_CODE, codeReason);
mIntent.putExtra(Constants.NOTIF_ID, notifId);

PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(con, 0, mIntent , 0);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(con)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .setContentTitle("test")
        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "action", mPendingIntent);
```

```
// Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(con, MainActivity.class);

PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        con, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
);

mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) con.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

mBuilder.setDefaults(
        Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND |
        Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE |
        Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS
);

// mId allows you to update the notification later on.
mNotificationManager.notify(notifId, mBuilder.build());
```

However the notification does not get hidden/dismissed although I know  I am hitting the code ( using log statements).

Why is that?

Comment: can you show the code where you are generating the notification ?

Comment: Code updated, notifId is generated number randomly that is passed in previoosly

Comment: where are you setting your notifId ? Because i think the problem is your notifId and the id should be same for canceling a notification that was used for generating.

Comment: Have you checked what value are you getting when you calling `intent.getIntExtra(Constants.NOTIF_ID, 0);` is zero???

Comment: I pass it in function that generates the notification. But I updated the code to show how I generate notification Id

Comment: maintain same notification id for cancel the notification

Comment: Yea I checked the received one is non 0 number

Comment: One another reason can be if you are generating multiple notification then notify id could be changed compared to the id you have generated notification

Comment: I just found that the notification Id that I used for generating notification is different than the notification I extract from intent. I guess thats the reason but the question is WHY!

Comment: So i guessed it rite. So question is are you generating multiple `notifications`.

Comment: But I am generating only one!  I have a breakpoint in the code above and only run once

Comment: Found the reason, check answer :)

Comment: Cool. Was thinking of the same thing.

Comment: It's weird they are identical although their intents have different destination classes. This what threw me off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. I "think" that due to the 2 pending intents having the same con and req code, they are ending up modifying their intent values. I fixed it by using 2 different request codes to ensure unique Pending Intents . Therefore , I got the same notifId

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your id if it's zero.
2. Check the notification is not binded with other Service by `startForeground()`.