# Cancelling notifications isn't working

Tags: android, notifications

I wrote a simple Linear layout for 2 buttons. One button for enabling notifications and another button for cancelling notifications:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"

        android:background="@color/black_60_opacity"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/submitDailyTime"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Submit"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"

        android:background="@color/black_60_opacity"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/cancelNot"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Cancel"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Then I wrote my `Notification code` as follows:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //CustomAlertDialog.showProgressDialog(getActivity(),"Requesting...");
        Intent intent;
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.submitDailyTime:
           /*     onBackPressed = true;
                userAccessTask = new KronosAsyncTask(getActivity(), utility.PunchIn(weekDay,calendar.getTime().toString(),"Out Punch"),this,AppConstants.urls.KRONOS_PUNCH,"json");
                userAccessTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);*/
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,14);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,18);
                intent = new Intent(getActivity(),NotificationReciever.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(),0,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),alarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
                break;

            case R.id.cancelNot:
                String ns = getActivity().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(ns);
                notificationManager.cancel(100);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Here is my `notification receiver` code:

```
package com.dell.kronos;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.dell.kronos.activities.MainActivity;


public class NotificationReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context,LaunchActivity.class);
        intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        //if we want ring on notifcation then uncomment below line//
        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,100,intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).
                setSmallIcon(R.drawable.kronos_logo).
                setContentIntent(pendingIntent).
                setContentText("Time to fill TimeSheet").
                setContentTitle("Hurry!!!").
                setSound(alarmSound).
        setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationManager.notify(100,builder.build());

    }
}
```

When I click on `Submit` button, I get notifications successfully. But when I click on `Cancel` button, notifications doesn't get cancelled. How to fix that?

Comment: Did u forget to assign the click listener on cancelNot?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33886277/notification-is-not-cancelled-after-calling-notification-cancel

Comment: @AlexChengalan: I'm using switch statement to redirect click actions to particular buttons

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to declare `cancelNot` and add `click listener` to `cancelNot`. So added these lines.

```
private TextView cancel;
cancel = ( TextView ) view.findViewById(R.id.cancelNot);
cancel.setOnClickListener(this);
```

And it worked

Comment: Thats what I mentioned in the comment :)

Comment: Yes, I was confused. Every programmer gets confused about codes written by himself :D